# Generate continuous character strings in a range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to generate all strings from `"aaa"` down to `"zzz"`. Currently, I'm doing this using 3 for loops, is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
key_options = []
for n1 in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    for n2 in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
        for n3 in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
             key_options.append(chr(n1) + chr(n2) + chr(n3))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> [''.join(p) for p in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'aae', ..., 'zzv', 'zzw', 'zzx', 'zzy', 'zzz']
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module is a much better way to do this sort of loop. The `product` function is what you’d use:

> **`itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])`**
>
> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

The [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) can provide the ASCII lowercase letters without using a `range`:

> **`string.ascii_lowercase`**
>
> The lowercase letters `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. This value is not locale-dependent and will not change.

Thus, you have

```
from itertools import product
from string import string

key_options = [''.join(n) for n in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> letters = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]
>>> letters
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

import itertools
["".join(i) for i in itertools.product(letters,letters,letters)]
```

Output

```
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', ... 'zzy', 'zzz']
```